# Laravel root directory updated, npm run dev creating app.css and app.js in wrong directory

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, webpack, laravel-mix

I'm working on a project, where I have to move Laravel's root directory into an `src` folder. and the content of the `public` folder is moved into the root directory.

My New folder structure is like this.

```
project_name 
   |css directory
   |js directory
   |index.php
   |src ->
        |app
        |bootstrap
        |config
        |database
        |node_modules
        |resources
        |routes
        |storage
        |routes
        |stubs
        |vendor
        |.env
        |composer.json
        |composer.lock     
        |package.lock
        |package.json
        |server.php
        |webpack.mix.js
        |artisan
```

I have updated the paths in the `index.php` file in the root directory with the below content.

```
<?php

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));

// require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
require __DIR__.'/src/vendor/autoload.php';

// $app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/src/bootstrap/app.php';


$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Now, When I run the `npm install` command under the `src` folder, it works fine, `php artisan` is also working fine.
But, when I run **npm run dev** or **npm run production**.

it creates a new `public` directory inside the `src` directory and creates new app.js and app.css files in it. Which is not required.

As per my new directory structure, they should now reside in the root directory under css and js folder respectively.

**webpack.mix.js**

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'js')
    .vue()
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'css');
```

Please Help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @matiaslauriti, This comment section is only for answers to the questions or related queries regarding the question. So, please stick to the question.

Now, in answer to your question, if the framework is built, in way that, its structure can be changed, then why not. If someone's requirement is not fulfilled with the given structure.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mix.setPublicPath()` to mix output file to the parent directory :

```js
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.setPublicPath('../../') // project root path
    .js('resources/js/app.js', 'js')
    .vue()
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'css');
```